# How to access value of multiselect with an array?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input, multi-select

I got my multiple select fields:

```
<select name="cars[]" id="cars" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
     <option value="black">Black</option>
     [..]
</select>
```

and this one:

```
<select name="cars[]" id="cars" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     <option value="volk">Volkswagen</option>
     [..]
</select>
```

when I select a random options and submit the form, do the `print_r` on the `$_POST` the output is:

```
[group] => Array
(
    [0] => audi
    [1] => volk
    [2] => black
)
```

I want to access the color now (it that case it would be the key no. `2` from the array), but the problem is that it may change, when I select other fields, eg. I select one car brand and one color... when then it looks like:

```
[group] => Array
(
    [0] => audi
    [1] => yellow
)
```

So the question is: Is there any way to always access the selected cars colour and cars brand? It would be nice if it would be separated, but its not and the array key is changeable.

Comment: Please provide more details to your question.

How do you want the data to be received by PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use different names (+ duplicate `id` is illegal and may cause problems)

```
<select name="cars_type[]" id="cars_type" multiple="multiple">
...
<select name="cars_color[]" id="cars_color" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: It needs to be in a one name because I need to validate it after that, in PHP and JS :/

Comment: I see no problem here. Validate them separately as they should be, because they are separate sets of values. You can always reformat the data once you have it on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You have not to use same id for your selects. Name them `cars_names` and `cars_colors` and you will have 2 separated arrays.